# How can I assign a type to an array of objects?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

**The Error is:** Type '{ id: string; title: string; content: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'InitialState': id, title, contentts(2739)

```
interface InitialState {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    content: string
    
}

const initialState:InitialState = [
   {id: '1', title: 'post title', content: 'the fack content'},
   {id: '1', title: 'post title', content: 'the fack content'},
]
```

Comment: Should be `const initialState: InitialState[] = [ ... ]`. Without typing `initialState` as an array the interpreter expects the value to be just one `InitialState`.

Comment: Yes I understand the matter, thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

Type of `initialState` is defined as `InitialState` but an array is passed instead. switch the type to be `InitialState[]`.